# Collecting updated values in a table using trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a situation, have a table of around 30+ columns created a audit table with same number of columns and few more additional columns  as description, updated date kind of columns. need a trigger to collect updated columns and collect them as description and need to form a sentence like so and so fields are updated into audit table. Help with sample trigger will be appreciated. Thanks in advance..

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_reservationdetail_audit]
ON [dbo].[tblReservationDetails]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT reservationDetails_audits(
        reservationDetailId,
        reservationId,
        rdCreationDate,
        rdItemTypeId,
        rdDeparture,
        rdArrival,
        rdPax,
        PaxChildren,
        PaxBabies,
        rdStatusId,
        rdIsCancelled,
        rdPackageId,
        rdRateId,
        rdPrice,
        rdTaxId,
        rdRoomId,
        rdTaxAmount,
        rdDays,
        siteId,
        CreatorID,
        CreatorName,
        Updated,
        UpdatedBy,
        Amount,
        Segment_ID,
        Source_ID,
        Remarks,
        SessionId,
        Contact_ID,
        CreatorContactProfileID,
        HotelReservationUniqueID,
        HotelReservationResID_Value,
        RoomStayId,
        ChnMgrContent_ID,
        InvoiceTo,
        SourceContext,
        BlockRoomChange,
        BlockRoomChangeReasonId,
        rdinvoiceid,
        isOnHoldResDet,
        updated_at,
        Operation,
        Description)
     SELECT
       i.reservationDetailId,
        reservationId,
        rdCreationDate,
        rdItemTypeId,
        rdDeparture,
        rdArrival,
        rdPax,
        PaxChildren,
        PaxBabies,
        rdStatusId,
        rdIsCancelled,
        rdPackageId,
        rdRateId,
        rdPrice,
        rdTaxId,
        rdRoomId,
        rdTaxAmount,
        rdDays,
        siteId,
        CreatorID,
        CreatorName,
        Updated,
        UpdatedBy,
        Amount,
        Segment_ID,
        Source_ID,
        Remarks,
        SessionId,
        Contact_ID,
        CreatorContactProfileID,
        HotelReservationUniqueID,
        HotelReservationResID_Value,
        RoomStayId,
        ChnMgrContent_ID,
        InvoiceTo,
        SourceContext,
        BlockRoomChange,
        BlockRoomChangeReasonId,
        rdinvoiceid,
        i.isOnHoldResDet,           
        GETDATE(),
   CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Deleted) THEN 'UPD' ELSE 'INS' END
FROM
   Inserted I
UNION ALL
SELECT
       d.reservationDetailId,
        reservationId,
        rdCreationDate,
        rdItemTypeId,
        rdDeparture,
        rdArrival,
        rdPax,
        PaxChildren,
        PaxBabies,
        rdStatusId,
        rdIsCancelled,
        rdPackageId,
        rdRateId,
        rdPrice,
        rdTaxId,
        rdRoomId,
        rdTaxAmount,
        rdDays,
        siteId,
        CreatorID,
        CreatorName,
        Updated,
        UpdatedBy,
        Amount,
        Segment_ID,
        Source_ID,
        Remarks,
        SessionId,
        Contact_ID,
        CreatorContactProfileID,
        HotelReservationUniqueID,
        HotelReservationResID_Value,
        RoomStayId,
        ChnMgrContent_ID,
        InvoiceTo,
        SourceContext,
        BlockRoomChange,
        BlockRoomChangeReasonId,
        rdinvoiceid,
        d.isOnHoldResDet,           
        GETDATE(),
        'DEL'
     FROM Deleted d
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM Inserted
);
END
```

Expecting a sample trigger with a new column in audit table as description which will form a simple sentence to display to users.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You question is not very clear. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Also try to create a minimal example. Showing all your columns in not relevant in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minor problem is comparing nullable columns. It can be done with an expression
`ISNULL(NULLIF(i.Col, d.Col), NULLIF(d.Col, i.Col)) IS NOT NULL` which is true if `inserted` and `deleted` row differs on `Col` .

```
INSERT reservationDetails_audits(
        reservationDetailId,
        reservationId,
        rdCreationDate,
        -- ..
        updated_at,
        Operation,
        Description)
SELECT
        i.reservationDetailId,
        i.reservationId,
        i.rdCreationDate,
        -- ..
        i.isOnHoldResDet,           
        GETDATE(),
        CASE WHEN d.reservationDetailId IS NOT NULL THEN 'UPD' ELSE 'INS' END,
        CASE WHEN d.reservationDetailId IS NOT NULL THEN
          ' updated cols: '
          -- assumming reservationId is not nullable
          + CASE i.reservationId <> d.reservationId THEN 'reservationId ' ELSE '' END 
          -- assumming rdCreationDate is nullable
          + CASE ISNULL(NULLIF(i.rdCreationDate, d.rdCreationDate), NULLIF(d.rdCreationDate, i.rdCreationDate)) IS NOT NULL THEN 'rdCreationDate ' ELSE '' END
          -- + ..
        ELSE '' END
FROM Inserted I
LEFT JOIN deleted d on d.reservationDetailId = i.reservationDetailId
UNION ALL
--  delete oper query
```

;

Comment: Thanks serg :) appreciate your time.